# Getting Count() for basic IQueryable instance

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework

I need to determine at runtime which view to populate `recordSet` from. However when I declare `recordSet` as `IQueryable` I lose access to functions like `Count()`.
If I declare `recordSet` as `IQueryable<View_A>` then I have access, but I've locked in the type. Is there some more generic type I could use with `IQueryable`?

```
IQueryable recordSet;

if (Flag)
    recordSet = db.View_A.Where(v => v.ID == Id);
else
    recordSet = db.View_B.Where(v => v.ID == Id);

int recordCount = recordSet.Count(); //complains about Count();
```

Comment: That is odd to me   IQueryable implments IEnumerable

Comment: @Blam neither `IQueryable` or `IEnumerable` has `Count()` extension methods. Only their generic counterparts does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`Count`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb468851%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) extension is meant for `IQueryable<>` type, which is why you cannot use it on `IQueryable`.

However, [covariance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) should allow your code to work if you declare your recordset this way:

```
IQueryable<Object> recordSet;
```

As noted by @hvd in the comments below, covariance here would only work with reference types.

Comment: 1) It should really be the `Queryable.Count` extension method, which is for `IQueryable<T>`, unless you want to retrieve all results from the database and count them in your program. 2) Covariance wouldn't allow treating `IQueryable<int>` as `IQueryable<object>`, it would only work for reference types. This restriction may or may not matter to the OP, but it should at least be mentioned in your answer.

Comment: @hvd 1) thanks, I tend to mix these two. 2) I assumed db entities wouldn't be structure types, but that's still a valid point. Added.